# Show calendar is broken in IBMNotes, Error: File does not exist

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a user which can't add other users calendars using the "Show calendar" feature, there is like 20 entries with "Error: File does not exist"

I have tried to remove the calendar profile, calendarProfile form and calendar view and did replace design, still the same problem

Any ideas?

Image show errors in the the calendar navigator in Notes 9.0.1

[image: Image show the calendar navigator in Notes 9.0.1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The settings for the other calendars is stored in the calendar profile in the item "CalURLs".

Sometimes this information becomes corrupted, resulting in such an error.

You can use tools like "notespeek" or Ytria ScanEZ to check the content of the field and fix it. Each entry looks like this consisting of display name, Type, User name, icon, background color, foreground color and some flags:

```
Micky Maus/Certifier'notesCalendar:Micky Maus/Certifier:0:null'calendar gray.png'{206,212,225}'{57,87,122}'1
```

To reset the entries (if you can't fix it with code) you can use this code in an agent or action button in the user's mailfile:

```
Dim ses as New NotesSession
Dim db as NotesDatabase
Dim docProfile as NotesDocument

Set db = ses.CurrentDatabase
Set docProfile = db.getProfileDocument( "CalendarProfile" )
if docProfile.HasItem( "CalURLs" ) then
  call docProfile.RemoveItem( "CalURLs" )
  call docProfile.Save( True, True, True )
  Messagebox "CalURLs habe been removed, please reopen the database and recreate them"
End if
```

This code is completely untested and might contain typos, but it should point you to the right direction.

Comment: I use ytria to remove, I have tried to remove the whole calendar profile and the CalUrl field but still same errors in navigator

Comment: Beware: The profile will be cached in your client. Close all open windows containing your mailfile, before manipulating the profile with ytria, that should fix it

Comment: I just tried it again now and this time it worked, thank you very much. another happy user :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's temporary files/AV related as outlined here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21605814

Quoted from the above technote:

> Cause
>
> Notes client temporary files are being inadvertently removed from the system running the Notes client.
>
> The (CalendarProfile) does in fact exist in the mail database.
>
> In some cases, anti-virus software has been implicated in deleting such files. The files have an extension of .DTF See http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/sep-detects-dtf-files-virus as an example.
>
> Resolving the problem
>
> A restart of the Notes client will typically resolve this problem.
>
> Upgrading to the latest version of anti-virus software is also recommended.
>
> Configuring the anti-virus software to exclude files with an extension of .DTF can prevent this problem from happening.
>
> Setting NOTES_TEMPDIR in the client's notes.ini file to a directory that is specifically used for storing such files can also help to prevent this problem.

You may also want to check the logs (`console*.log`), they are normally located in `<Install_root>\Notes\Data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT`

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove my calendar profile using IBM's [AdminTools 1.3](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21459332) as explained [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ndseforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=73397408A3FD7DBF85257EA7002665FE) instead. I did not have the right to use agents in my mail file so this solution worked.

Finally, after opening Calendar and going to `More` -> `Preferences` also the problem of specifying the owner of the mailfile (nagging popup when opening Calendar) goes away which was caused by deleting the profile.